# uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token = in chrome for bigpipe.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

I am using bigpipe.js method to my website for displaying newsfeed.It is working fine in all the browsers except google chrome.In chrome its showing 'uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token = ' error.Please help me to rectify this error.

Comment: Can you show us where this error is getting thrown. Can you post that line of code.

Comment: <script>function photoPopUp(aid,im_type,im_cat=0){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like that

```
function photoPopUp(aid,im_type,im_cat){
    if (typeof(im_cat) === undefined) im_cat = 0
    // your code here
}
```